# Vertical charts, CSS, Divs and MySql

Tags: html, mysql, css

I have a table:

```
    ID       | title    | start_line | line_height | studio 
    -------- |----------|------------|-------------|-------
    1        | Title 1  |     2      |      7      |   1
    1        | Title 2  |     15     |      4      |   1
    1        | Title 3  |     6      |      5      |   2
    1        | Title 4  |     12     |      5      |   3
```

and I would like to replicate it with css like that

[image]

Any suggestions or directions? (I would like to avoid any JavaScript)

Comment: What is your effort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in HTML with embedded css :
A main div contain 4 columns (inline-block divs, with fixed 100% height i.e.).
Each dynamic column is populated with one "legend" div, and some "event" divs. Each one having "position:relative" attribute (via a class), "height" and "top" properties are given inline. The result should look like :

```
<div class="table">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="legend" style="top:0%;height:4.76%">Studio 1</div>
    <div class="event" style="top:16.66%;height:32.5%">Title X / Height Y</div>
  ....
  </div>
</div>
```

Generating this from php shouldn't be a real problem :

```
echo '<div class="event" style="top:'.(100*$res["start_line"]/21).
'%;height:'.(100*$res["line_height"]/21).'%">Title X / Height Y</div>';
```

Same for the first column :

```
for($i=0;i<22;$i++) {
echo '<div class="legend" style="top:'.(100*$i/21).'%;height:'.(100/21).'%">'.$i.'</div>';
}
```

Last step is to add the grid on each column. You can find pure CSS trick to do this (might be unreliable), or use a streched background-image on each column.